# NumberFormatException when trying to read user input

Tags: java

I am new to Java and writing a program to show names, address, phone number, and birthday where name & phone number are `public`, birthday is `private`, and other info is `protected`.

Here is my core class:

```
public class newd {

    public int Name;
    public int Phone_no;
    protected String Address;
    protected int Age;
    private int Birth_day;

    void GetData() throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader IN = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IN);

        System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
        String S1 = BR.readLine();
        Name = Integer.parseInt(S1);

        System.out.print("Enter Phone_no : ");
        String S2 = BR.readLine();
        Phone_no = Integer.parseInt(S2);

        System.out.print("Enter Address : ");
        String S3 = BR.readLine();
        Age = Integer.parseInt(S3);

        System.out.print("Enter Age : ");
        String S4 = BR.readLine();
        Age = Integer.parseInt(S4);

        System.out.print("Enter Birth_day : ");
        String S5 = BR.readLine();
        Birth_day = Integer.parseInt(S5);

    }

    void Display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name : " + Name);
        System.out.println("Phone No : " + Phone_no);
        System.out.println("Address : " + Address);
        System.out.println("Age : " + Age);
        System.out.println("Birth Day : " + Birth_day); 
    }

}
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
public class newdirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        newd D = new newd();

        D.GetData();
        D.Display();

    }

}
```

When I compile the program, it shows this dialog.

```
Enter Name : kamrul
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kamrul"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at newd.GetData(newd.java:21)
    at newdirectory.main(newdirectory.java:9)
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are trying to parse your name into an int, this will off course not work, Kamrul is not an int so java gives you an exception, a java.lang.NumberFormatException go read java API for full details

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
String S1 = BR.readLine();
Name = Integer.parseInt(S1);
```

`parseInt(...)` only works if the string passed in can be parsed as an integer, or else, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

Refer to [this link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

In your case, I suppose it should be:

```
public String Name;
```

and you will just need to do this:

```
System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
Name = BR.readLine();
```

Same for address:

```
System.out.print("Enter Address : ");
Address = BR.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Enter Address : ");
String S3 = BR.readLine();
Age = Integer.parseInt(S3);
```

This is the problem in your code. You are trying to get convert a string data to integer and hence the exception.

Also change your public instance varaibles to protected/private. varaibles should not be exposed as public unless they are constants .

Reference on Variable Declarations:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are trying to convert a non-numeric string to a Number, in this case you will receive `NumberFormatException`. To make things clear, "avadakadavra" is a non-numeric string and "1234" is numeric string which can be converted to a `Integer` or a `Float`, whereas the former cannot be converted.

I have included an example to work with dates using calender and included quick reference and examples.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class newd {

    public String Name;
    public int Phone_no;
    protected String Address;
    protected int Age;
    private Calendar Birth_day;

    void GetData() throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader IN = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IN);

        System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
        Name = BR.readLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Phone_no : ");
        Phone_no = Integer.parseInt(BR.readLine());

        System.out.print("Enter Address : ");
        Address = BR.readLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Age : ");
        String S4 = BR.readLine();
        Age = Integer.parseInt(S4);

        System.out.print("Enter Birth_day MM/DD/YYYY: ");
        String[] date = ((String)BR.readLine()).split("/");
        Birth_day = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(date[2]),Integer.parseInt(date[1]),Integer.parseInt(date[0]));

    }

    void Display()
    {
         System.out.println("Name : " + Name);
         System.out.println("Phone No : " + Phone_no);
         System.out.println("Address : " + Address);
         System.out.println("Age : " + Age);
         System.out.println("Birth Day : " + Birth_day.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + Birth_day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + Birth_day.get(Calendar.YEAR)); 
     }
}
```

Date in java previously were managed with Date class available in `JAVA.UTIL.DATE` but with the introduction of Calender, available in the same package, date handling has improved. 
[for quick tutorial on Calendar](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_calendar.htm) and [Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a Conclusion the problem is you are converting Characters in Numbers, Since this is not possible, your program is throwing a Exception called Number Format Exception.
Solution is Just remove the lines of code having `Integer.parseInt(S1)` & `Integer.parseInt(S3)` Since these both are trying to Convert Name & Address into Numbers thus raising an exception.